# compare directory files with mapping file for new added and deleted files from same directory

Tags: shell

In a directory i have few files as:

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
z.txt
```

and in different directory i have a file name called map_file with data like:

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
d.txt
e.txt
f.txt
```

I want to compare(only filenames not content of filenames) files exits in directory with the filenames that are in map_file.

1. if new file is found in directory(does not exits in map_file)then copy and rename file to some other directory.
2. if file is not present in the directory(as per map_file),then also copy and rename to some directory.

with below sample code I'm only getting first condition not both.

sample code which I'm using is

```
for file in *.txt
do
if [[ ! $(grep "$file" /path/to/map_file) ]]; then
   echo "$file is not in map_file -- copy/rename somewhere else."
   cp ${file} ../Add-${file}
fi
done
```

so final output should looks like:

```
Add-z.txt                   Del-d.txt
                            Del-e.txt
                            Del-f.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cd path/to/directory
map_file=path/to/map.txt
for file in `ls -lrt *.txt | awk '{print $9}'`
do
if [[ ! $(grep "$file" $map_file) ]];
then
   echo "$file is not present in map_file"
   #cp ${file} ../Add-${file}
else
    while IFS= read line
    do
        if [ ! -f "$line" ];
        then
            #touch ../Del-${line}
        fi
    done <"$map_file"
fi
done
```

Please take a look at my answer and reply if can be optimized further.